# Regex to exclude a specific pattern python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find any occurunce of "fiction" preceeded or followed by anything, except for "non-"

I tried :

> ***.*[^(n-)]fiction.****

but it's not working as I want it to.
Can anyone help me out?

[image: example]

Comment: you want a negative lookbehind. Something like [[^\s]*(?<!n-)fiction which will match any number of non white space characters prior to finding the word fiction unless--imediately prior to finding the word fiction--if finds the characters "n-"

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this works for you:

```
.*(?<!non\-)fiction.*
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid patterns starting with `.*`: they cause too many backtracking steps and slow down the code execution.

In Python, you may always get lines either by reading a file line by line, or by splitting a line with `splitlines()` and then get the necessary lines by testing them against a pattern without `.*`s.

1. Reading a file line by line:

```py
final_output = []
with open(filepath, 'r', newline="\n", encoding="utf8") as f:
  for line in f:
    if "fiction" in line and "non-fiction" not in line:
      final_output.append(line.strip())
```

Or, getting the lines even with `non-fiction` if there is `fiction` with no `non-` in front using a bit modified [@jlesuffleur's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66508877/3832970):

```
import re
final_output = []
rx = re.compile(r'\b(?<!non-)fiction\b')
with open(filepath, 'r', newline="\n", encoding="utf8") as f:
  for line in f:
    if rx.search(line):
      final_output.append(line.strip())
```

2. Getting lines from a multiline string (with both approaches mentioned above):

```py
import re
text = "Your input string line 1\nLine 2 with fiction\nLine 3 with non-fiction\nLine 4 with fiction and non-fiction"
rx = re.compile(r'\b(?<!non-)fiction\b')
# Approach with regex returning any line containing fiction with no non- prefix:
final_output = [line.strip() for line in text.splitlines() if rx.search(line)]
# => ['Line 2 with fiction']
# Non-regex approach that does not return lines that may contain non-fiction (if they contain fiction with no non- prefix):
final_output = [line.strip() for line in text.splitlines() if "fiction" in line and "non-fiction" not in line]
# => ['Line 2 with fiction', 'Line 4 with fiction and non-fiction']
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/t10ltL).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What about a negative lookbehind?

```
s = 'fiction non-fiction'
res = re.findall("(?<!non-)fiction", s)
res
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but it only exctracts the word "fiction" even if it's proceeded by non-